# how to use backgroundworker with remote class

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

How do I report change of the CountValue from this class to a backgroundworker

```
class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void CountUp()
    {
        int CountValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            CountValue = i;
    }
}
```

Here is the implemetation of the DoWork function

```
   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        SomeOtherClass MyOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
        int CountValue;
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MyOtherClass.CountUp();
            worker.ReportProgress(CountValue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way that SomeOtherClass looks now there is no obvious way. If you can change SomeOtherClass you could add an event:

```
class CountEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int CountValue { get; private set; }
    public CountEventArgs (int countValue)
    {
        CountValue = countValue;
    }
}
class SomeOtherClass
{
    public event EventHandler<CountEventArgs> CountValueChanged;
    public void CountUp()
    {
        int CountValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            CountValue = i;
            OnCountValueChanged(new CountEventArgs(CountValue));
        }
    }
    private void OnCountValueChanged(CountEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<CountEventArgs> temp = CountValueChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can set up an event handler and use the ReportProgress method of the BackgroundWorker to relay the information to the UI:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
SomeOtherClass MyOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
// set up an anonymous method as event handler for the CountValueChanged
// event. This event handler passes the count value on to the ReportProgress
// method of the background worker, which in turn will raise the ProgressChanged
// event on the UI thread.
MyOtherClass.CountValueChanged += (eventSender, eventArgs) =>
{
    worker.ReportProgress(eventArgs.CountValue);
};

MyOtherClass.CountUp();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made a lot of errors in your code. In particular, you can't expect Windows to keep up when you are sending it a new event millions of times per second. Try only sending an update when you have completed a large block of work. Also, the parameter for ReportProgress should be a percentage (0 - 100). If you want to send data other than a percentage, use the user state parameter. Here is some code you can use:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

            int countValue = 0;
            int max = 100000000;
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }

                countValue = i;
                if (i % 1000000 == 0)
                    worker.ReportProgress(i / (max / 100), i);
            }
            worker.ReportProgress(100, max);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            labelCounter.Text = ((int)e.UserState).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: remember to set the worker's SupportsProgress and SupportsCancellation to true in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand but I'll give it a shot. Why not change CountUp() to return a value?

```
public int CountUp()    
{
    int CountValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        CountValue = i;    

    return CountValue;
}
```

The purpose of this code doesn't make sense to me so I'm not sure I understand what you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how local variables work... the `CountValue` in your `CountUp` method will only write to the local variable in your `CountUp` method. It does not affect the `CountUp` variable in your `backgroundWorker_DoWork` method. You would have to move `CountUp` to the DoWork method for it to work.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        if (worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        worker.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well he could expose the value through a property of SomeClass but it wouldn't change the fact that the call to MyOtherClass.CountUp() will block.

Comment: the countUp method was just an example. The method I'm using is too big to put it into the DoWork method. So I need to understand what I have to do to access the CountValue from within the DoWork method

Comment: Perhaps do what Cory suggested, by exposing it through a property, like so: `public int Count { get { return _count; } }`, assuming you had an instance variable called `_count`.